# Rails Gem - Peddler for Amazon API

Tags: amazon-web-services, rubygems, amazon-mws

Looking for some examples to figure out this gem.. Here is the link:
https://github.com/hakanensari/peddler

Not so clear on the "client" creation they speak on.

Anyone use this one before? Any help or direction is MUCH appreciated.

Thanks
Todd

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step 1 - add the gem to your gemfile:**

```
gem "peddler"
```

(Don't forget to bundle install after)

**Step 2 - create the client in your code: (i pulled this code from a controller)**

*by hardcoding values*

```
client = MWS::Products::Client.new(
  marketplace_id:        'foo',
  merchant_id:           'bar',
  aws_access_key_id:     'foobar',
  aws_secret_access_key: 'barfoo'
)
```

*or using environment variables you set in your shell*

```
client = MWS::Products::Client.new(
  marketplace_id:        ENV['MARKETPLACE_ID'],
  merchant_id:           ENV['MERCHANT_ID'],
  aws_access_key_id:     ENV['AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
  aws_secret_access_key: ENV['AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY']
)
```

**Step 3 - make a call**

*example1:*

```
response = client.get_matching_product('B00N1EJXUU')
```

*example2:*

```
response = client.get_matching_product_for_id('UPC','849803051044')
```

To inspect, call:

```
puts response.to_yaml
```

Comment: Hell yea!!!!!! It worked.. I swear this was exactly what I was doing before, and getting No method errors.. but then I just got a not authorized error, and updated my keys and it worked!!! Wahoo.. thank you soo much!!

Comment: Do you happen to have an example for outbound fulfillments? All I get is response 400: bad request. Can't seem to figure out where my error is.. Followed the documentation as closely as possible but it isn't the most detailed documentation.